# RVM: create a gemset that doesn't inherit from global?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I'm starting work on a project written in Rails 2.  It looks like it requires an older version of Rake, which is in my global gemset for Ruby 1.8.7.  I'd like to avoid uninstalling the global 1.8.7 rake just for this one app.

Is there anyway I can create a gemset that would ignore the global gemset?

Edit: the most obvious solution I want to avoid is uninstalling gems from the global gemset.  In my particular situation I started some work on a legacy app.  It breaks with gems like rake 0.9.3 and my debugging gems (awesome_print, hirb, wirb, etc).  While my current solution (in the comment below) is a hack, it appears to be the least amount of work for what I want.  I was hoping that there was some gemset exception command that I didn't know about.

Comment: My current solution: install the next-most-recent patchlevel.  Currently this is 1.8.7-p299.  My main is 1.8.7-p352.  This works as the p299 and p352 interpreters don't share global gemsets.  It feels very much like a hack, though, so I'd still like to see a cleaner solution, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to run `rvm gemset empty test` on your newly created gemset to remove all gems (local and global), then an `bundle install` should only install the gemfile gems.

Comment: This is useful, but `rvm gemset empty` doesn't remove the global gems unless I switch to the global gemset first.  This is a less spaghetti-ish option than what I currently have, so it's interesting.  For N projects that require the same core gems/versions (i.e. rake, ruby-debug, etc), I'd have to reinstall the gems for those N projects so that I don't have them in 1.

Answer (score -2):

Yes you can. You need to run `rvm gemset create {gemset_name}`.
That will create an empty gemset, and you'll have to install all the gems with their versions in there (just gem install ..., without sudo).

Comment: I just ran `rvm gemset create {test}` and the {test} gem still inherits gems from the global gemset.

Comment: it shouldn't...run it without the brackets

Comment: I think you're mistaken.  RVM creates an @global gemset for every interpreter you install, i.e. ruby-1.8.7-p299@global.  Any gemset installed in this interpreter will have its own gems *plus* the gems in the global gemset.  What I'd like to do is install one single gemset which ignores one or more gems from the global.

Comment: Not a solution to the problem. This method still results in gems flowing through from the global gemset